# Question on output impedance vs voltage and current

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

If output impedance of a op-amp is low wouldn't the output voltage be low? Why would you want that?
The same for a current amp i.e the high output impedance will give low output current why is this ideal?

Comment: You're providing two unrelated examples and your facts are dogmatic. How on Earth are you making these assumptions?

Answer (score 1):

> If output impedance of a op-amp is low wouldn't the output voltage be
>   low? Why would you want that?

No, the output impedance is a *source impedance*, which can be thought of like a resistance in series with the output. If the output impedance is low, then you can source more current to your load.

> The same for a current amp i.e the high output impedance will give low
>   output current why is this ideal?

Current amps are have low impedance outputs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOGPJW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Output impedance of opamps depends on the internal circuitry, external feedback, and on frequency at which you measure the Zout.

Lotta bipolar opamps have 100_ohm Rout, because of the class-B output circuitry.

I've seen CMOS opamps with 100,000 ohm Rout.

Feedback usually lowers these values.

simply google "opamp rout"